# Tracing the source of memory leak in Volley

Tags: android, leakcanary

I'm having trouble pointing out where is the leak that `LeakCanary` is telling me. I am using the [VolleyPlus](https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus) library and tried to dig inside the code that might be the cause of the leak but still can't identify it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: why VolleyPlus?

Comment: @ZaidMirza That's what they were using before I came and they are planning to use Retrofit but now, I am tasked to fix this.